# Can you optimize this PHP loop query code?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, optimization, query-optimization

I got some performance problems with my Laravel website.
I was able to find out that the reason of that is a part of my code.
I do queries in a loop which shouldn't be done as I just found out.
I m not sure how i can optimize this code in the best way (without changing the database since that is not as easy at this point of the project).

I was thinking about improving the part with the `foreach` `$transactionInfos` atleast kinda like this, but i'm not sure about the Laravel syntax with that right now:

```php
$transactionInfos = ToolTransactionInfo::where('tool_id', $tool->id)
                    ->where('date', $date)
                    ->only(['users'])
                    //->get();
                    ->all();

if(!empty($transactionInfos)) {
                    $users = array_sum($transactionInfos);
                }
                else{
                    $users = 0;
                }
```

The actual code:

```php
        foreach ($data['tools'] as $tool) {
            // 30 day user graph data
            $count = 30;
            $tool_users_30d[$tool->id] = [];
            while ($count > 0) {
                $date = Carbon::now()->subDays($count)->format('Y-m-d');

                $transactionInfos = ToolTransactionInfo::where('tool_id', $tool->id)
                    ->where('date', $date)
                    ->get();

                $users = 0;
                foreach ($transactionInfos as $transactionInfo) {
                    $users += $transactionInfo->users;
                } 

                array_push($tool_users_30d[$tool->id], $users);
                $count--;
            }
        }
        $data['tool_users_30d'] = $tool_users_30d;
```

I expect to get an array with a list of all tools with arrays of each 30day user data, for example:

- [13][0] = 20
- [13][1] = 6
- [13][2] = 24
- ..
- [13][29] = 10
- ..
- [18][0] = 50
- [18][1] = 11
- [18][2] = 55
- ..
- [18][29] = 6

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUmEw.png
(the example image shows 0 user because of a local empty DB but that's how it should look like).

Comment: Show us the generated SQL so we can approach the problem from that side.

Comment: I had a similar issue with the creation of stats. I solved it with caching in combination with a generated command and scheduling. You know that past data won't change. If the current day changes, adapt the cached data on that particular place in the multidim array and resave the cache. That can be done by creating an event in combination with queues. Run the 30d schedule at midnight. If the cache(d array) is too big, you may save it as a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the entire algorithm to a single sql query, something like this (havent run it, it needs some quotes at least...), you will just need a single pass through the result to construct the target multidimensional array.

```
SELECT tool_id, 30 - datediff(now(), date) as "offset", sum(users)
FROM transaction_info
WHERE date >= (date(now()) - interval 30 days) AND date < date(now())
GROUP BY tool_id, 30 - datediff(now(), date)
```

Comment: Will see how to make that query in laravel and give feedback if it worked.

Comment: The SQL query works and seems to be the right ways, i will write the laravel code when i got it.

Comment: ok, btw, the part with "30 - datediff(now(), date)", that is there just to fit your offsets perfectly, but i think it might perform better if you have this just "select date group by date", and count the offset (days before today) on the php side. so it could be better for performance, and after all it may even be easier to fit to the laravel wrappers...

Comment: yes, i thought the same i used just date. Just checking how to make the array as needed after the query, will post it soon for review.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do to help speed this up to improve performance, and reduce your hits to the database / call to function.

First, you can pull all of your `ToolTransactionInfo` at once, before you loop.  This will help you to only do one DB pull.  So, above your loop:

```
$transactionInfosTotal = ToolTransactionInfo::get();
```

This gives you all the infos you need.  Then, inside your loop, you can do the same query, but do it on the collection already in memory (ie don't go back to the DB).

```
 $transactionInfos = $transactionInfosTotal->where('tool_id', $tool->id)  
                ->where('date', $date)
                ->get();
```

With this, you get the same collection inside your loops, for the right day and tool - and you can then perform your calcs or move to an array as you wish.  This just saves the DB hits / makes it more efficient and faster.

The other thing that you can do to speed up a little bit is to call the time (Carbon) once.  Not a huge savings, but it will probably be a little bit faster:. Before your loops, set 'now' into a variable:

```
$now = Carbon(now);
```

Then use that value stored in the variable inside your loops to work your time calcs, as it doesn't have to go back to the method to get now, it already has it in memory:

```
$date = $now->subDays($count)->format('Y-m-d');
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Unfortuanly i get the following error at this point "where('tool_id', $tool->id)"
Non-static method Illuminate\Support\Collection::where() should not be called statically.

Comment: Ooops - sorry - make it non-static.   `$transactionInfosTotal->where('tool_id', $tool->id)`.  I will edit my answer to fix.

Comment: It doesnt need the ->get(); at the  $transactionInfos.
Then $now = Carbon(now); doesnt work because it will sub the now by doing $now->subDays($count) so i sub the subbed all the time instead of taking the now from carbon again to reset it.

Comment: Unfortuanly this makes it even slower since it has to load 150k data in one query. With the other one it make like 50 DB queries but each only picks 30 data. its 30sec vs 5sec.

Comment: Yep, I see what you mean.  With that volume of data, you will need to tune the query to take a slice.  Still recommend you don't do it in the loop, but do a pre-query with some level of filtering ahead.  30 seconds is crazy long for a query - even that volume.  With the $now thing, use a second temp variable - that's still the right method, rather than calling each time.

Comment: I tried it with a second temp variable, it still changes the main one.

Comment: @DappFuture dude, check my answer, it will give you the entire result directly from db with single query. no additional data transfered between php and db.

Answer (score 0):

The query of slepic was the way to go. It improved the total page load from 3.8 to 2.5 seconds (heavy data page but still some improvements todo) but this was one of the 2 heaviest functions i could improve. Thank you slepic and all other suggestions.

Here is my solution:

```php
        // 30 day user graph data
        // Prepare array list
        $loaded_tool_ids = [];
        foreach ($data['tools'] as $tool) {
            array_push($loaded_tool_ids, $tool->id);
        }
        $count = 30;
        $now = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
        $oldest_date = Carbon::now()->subDays($count)->format('Y-m-d');
        // Query tool history data
        $transactionInfos = ToolTransactionInfo::select('tool_id','date',DB::raw("SUM(users) as users"))
            ->whereIn('tool_id', $loaded_tool_ids)
            ->where('date', '>=', $oldest_date)
            ->where('date', '<', $now)
            ->groupBy('tool_id')
            ->groupBy('date')
            ->orderBy('tool_id', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('date', 'asc')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();

        // Fill output array with query data
        foreach($transactionInfos as $transactionInfo) {
            // Get date number
            $date_number = $count - Carbon::parse($transactionInfo['date'])->diffInDays($now);
            // Fill array
            if(!empty($tool_users_30d[$transactionInfo['tool_id']])){
                // Fill previous dates with 0 data
                $tool_users_30d[$transactionInfo['tool_id']][$date_number] = (int) $transactionInfo['users'];
            }
            else{
                // Create array with the tool id
                $tool_users_30d[$transactionInfo['tool_id']] = [];
                // Fill date
                $tool_users_30d[$transactionInfo['tool_id']][$date_number] = (int) $transactionInfo['users'];
            }
        }

        // Fill output array with loaded tools that have empty days
        foreach($loaded_tool_ids as $loaded_tool_id){
            if(empty($tool_users_30d[$loaded_tool_id])){
                // Create array with the tool id
                $tool_users_30d[$loaded_tool_id] = [];
            }
        }

        // Fill days with 0 data
        foreach($tool_users_30d as $key => $tool_users){
            while($count > 0){
                if(empty($tool_users[$count-1])){
                    $tool_users_30d[$key][$count-1] = 0;
                }
                $count--;
            }
            $count = 30;
            ksort($tool_users_30d[$key]);
        }
        $data['tool_users_30d'] = $tool_users_30d;
```

Comment: btw, you may want to add compound index on (tool_id, date), see if it makes any difference. Well, I suppose tool_id already has an index. In that case incorporate the date column in this index, instead of creating another one. Also try an alone index on the date column. See which would be better. The need of indexes is not static, it depends on the size of the table and ability of queries to utilize the index. So it needs adjusting over time...